# CSS: toggle accordion panel?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to create an accordion panel using css and small bit of javascript.

Everything seems to work fine apart from the toggling the panels.

So basically, when one panel is clicked, I need all other open panels to be closed.

Here is a fiddle:

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/upsqpyz3/)

I tried to do it this way but that keeps all the panels closed all the time:

```
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
    acc[i].onclick = function(){
        this.classList.toggle("active");
        $('.panel').addClass('hide');
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("hide");
        this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

and the CSS part:

```
.panel.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;  
}
```

I also tried :

```
$(this).removeClass('hide');
```

I know this is jquery and not pure Javascript but I thought I could work but didn't.

could someone please advise on this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have jQuery in the page?

Comment: @ArunPJohny, yes, i do...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the click handler get the active item, it is not the current item then remove the active state from it.

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #CBF1F5;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #3CF;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #E1F7FB;
}
button.accordion:after {
  content: '\25bc';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\25b2";
  color: #FFF;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.panel.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

---

With jQuery

```js
$('.accordion').click(function() {
  var $this = $(this).toggleClass('active');
  var $panel = $this.next().toggleClass('show');
  $('.accordion.active').not(this).removeClass('active').next().removeClass('show');
});
```

```css
button.accordion {
  background-color: #CBF1F5;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 18px;
  width: 100%;
  border: solid 1px #3CF;
  text-align: left;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.4s;
  font-weight: 600;
}
button.accordion.active,
button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #E1F7FB;
}
button.accordion:after {
  content: '\25bc';
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #777;
  float: right;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button.accordion.active:after {
  content: "\25b2";
  color: #FFF;
}
.panel {
  padding: 0 18px;
  background-color: white;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}
.panel.show {
  opacity: 1;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.panel.hide {
  opacity: 0;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>


<button class="accordion">Section 2</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>



<button class="accordion">Section 3</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the jquery one as well. jQuery one is more straight forward so i might use the jquery as opposed to the pure js.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .not selector... you don't need a for with jquery

JS:

```
var acc = $(".accordion"); //jquery accordion

acc.click(function() //when we click on element
{ 
    $(this).toggleClass("active");  //it is active
    $('.panel').not($(this).next()).hide(); //we hide all panels but not the next element
    $(this).next().toggle(); //and we show the next element
});
```