# Accordion group how to modify code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, accordion

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

var accd = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-deep");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion-deep.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active-deep");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active-depp");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
<button class="accordion-deep">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel-deep">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

I found code like this in thread and it works great, but i need to put another accordion in to section 1. Right now when i do this, section 1 is closing when i click on deeper accordion panel. 
I was trying to add another var to deeper accordion but this didin't work.

[CSS: toggle accordion panel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36643811/css-toggle-accordion-panel/36644028)

Comment: Please first edit your post by adding `css code` to it, since it does not work at the moment. You can try and see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided a css, i can only assume that you copied from the other example. I made changes to your code, and it is working now.

But before that, you had syntax errors with your code. Such as :

```
this.classList.toggle("active-depp");
```

should be

```
this.classList.toggle("active-deep");
```

also all of the `acc` should be `accd` on the second function.
but the most important thing is, you have to duplicate css for `accordion-deep` and `panel-deep` Such as

```js
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {
  acc[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}

var accd = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion-deep");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < accd.length; i++) {
  accd[i].onclick = function() {
    var active = document.querySelector(".accordion-deep.active");
    if (active && active != this) {
      active.classList.remove("active-deep");
      active.nextElementSibling.classList.remove("show");
    }
    this.classList.toggle("active-deep");
    this.nextElementSibling.classList.toggle("show");
  }
}
```

```css
 button.accordion, button.accordion-deep {
 background-color:#CBF1F5;
 
    color: #444;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    border:solid 1px #3CF;
    text-align: left;
    outline: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    transition: 0.4s;
 font-weight:600;
}

button.accordion.active, button.accordion-deep.active, button.accordion:hover, button.accordion-deep:hover {
    background-color: #E1F7FB;
}

button.accordion:after, button.accordion-deep:after {
    content: '\25bc';
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #777;
    float: right;
    margin-left: 5px;
}

button.accordion.active:after, button.accordion-deep.active:after {
    content: "\25b2";
 color:#FFF;

}

.panel, .panel-deep {
    padding: 0 18px;
    background-color: white;
    max-height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s ease-in-out;
    opacity: 0;
}

.panel.show, .panel-deep.show {
    opacity: 1;
    max-height: 500px;  
}

.panel.hide, .panel-deep.hide {
    opacity: 0;
    height: 0;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="accordion">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel">
<button class="accordion-deep">Section 1</button>
<div id="foo" class="panel-deep">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Hope it helps.

> EDIT : With this workaround, you can go one-level deep. But if you want to go deep, it is not an elegant way of writing code this way like copying each time you wanna go deep.

Comment: Yeah I know but right know i must do something to make this working. When I will have more time, I want to rewrite everything from beginning.

Comment: This is exactly what he asked for.